# How to extract values from a custom json string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I extract values from the below mentioned JSON using java script?

```
var json = {
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3628800",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "981",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Date": "Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:52:27 GMT",
    "Server": "Apigee LB"
  },
  "content": "{\n  \"apiProducts\" : [ ],\n  \"appFamily\" : \"default\",\n  \"appId\" : \"a937ece1-a0be-4475-bfea-e11fdeb279c6\",\n  \"attributes\" : [ {\n    \"name\" : \"DisplayName\",\n    \"value\" : \"CustomerApp\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\" : \"Notes\",\n    \"value\" : \"\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\" : \"fusion.expiry.date\",\n    \"value\" : \"2/10/2017\"\n  } ],\n  \"callbackUrl\" : \"\",\n  \"createdAt\" : 1484029734897,\n  \"createdBy\" : \"suvojitc@rssoftware.co.in\",\n  \"credentials\" : [ {\n    \"apiProducts\" : [ {\n      \"apiproduct\" : \"Customer and Product\",\n      \"status\" : \"revoked\"\n    } ],\n    \"attributes\" : [ ],\n    \"consumerKey\" : \"wNy0oKRhisvtMpjCR3dp67vZAC5lV3NV\",\n    \"consumerSecret\" : \"mTiGGgHoAAGrqWmh\",\n    \"expiresAt\" : 1486621737213,\n    \"issuedAt\" : 1484029737213,\n    \"scopes\" : [ ],\n    \"status\" : \"approved\"\n  } ],\n  \"developerId\" : \"793e585c-f093-41d6-88e9-e235bfd087ed\",\n  \"lastModifiedAt\" : 1484049963233,\n  \"lastModifiedBy\" : \"suvojitc@rssoftware.co.in\",\n  \"name\" : \"CustomerApp\",\n  \"scopes\" : [ ],\n  \"status\" : \"approved\"\n}",
  "status": {
    "message": "OK",
    "code": "200"
  }
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Use dot notation. `json.headers[0].Connection;`

Comment: It looks like you aren't working with JSON. You have an actual JS object (JSON is just a text format which needs to be parsed to be useful). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Json is made for Javascript. All you should need to do is `json.headers.Connection`, which should retrieve `keep-alive`.

Rinse and repeat. Otherwise, get a parsing library.

The exception is with non-regular symbols in variable names. Note that dot notation will not accept `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, instead it will throw an error. To get around this, use the box notation.

`json.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]` which will retrieve `origin`

The box notation takes in strings, so you must have the quote around `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

`json.headers[Access-Control-Allow-Headers]` will also throw a syntax error.

Edit: As Mike C rightly points out, the '.' notation will not accept the '-' symbol.

Comment: This is a correct way and probably be the way to use it, however, there is another way to access the data. `json['headers']['Access-control-allow-headers']` which will get you the same output for origin.

Comment: `json.headers.Access-control-allow-headers` would result in a syntax error since you can't have `-` in identifiers. Instead, you'd need to do `json.headers['Access-control-allow-headers]'`

Comment: @MikeC - You are quite right. I never use '-' in my variable names. I've never had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. As first you need to convert it to json string and then convert it to json object so that you can fetch the value with required key.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
 var json={    
   "headers": {
   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
   "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3628800",
   "Connection": "keep-alive",
   "Content-Length": "981",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Date": "Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:52:27 GMT",
   "Server": "Apigee LB"
  },
  "content": "{\n  \"apiProducts\" : [ ],\n  \"appFamily\" : \"default\",\n  \"appId\" : \"a937ece1-a0be-4475-bfea-e11fdeb279c6\",\n  \"attributes\" : [ {\n    \"name\" : \"DisplayName\",\n    \"value\" : \"CustomerApp\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\" : \"Notes\",\n    \"value\" : \"\"\n  }, {\n    \"name\" : \"fusion.expiry.date\",\n    \"value\" : \"2/10/2017\"\n  } ],\n  \"callbackUrl\" : \"\",\n  \"createdAt\" : 1484029734897,\n  \"createdBy\" : \"suvojitc@rssoftware.co.in\",\n  \"credentials\" : [ {\n    \"apiProducts\" : [ {\n      \"apiproduct\" : \"Customer and Product\",\n      \"status\" : \"revoked\"\n    } ],\n    \"attributes\" : [ ],\n    \"consumerKey\" : \"wNy0oKRhisvtMpjCR3dp67vZAC5lV3NV\",\n    \"consumerSecret\" : \"mTiGGgHoAAGrqWmh\",\n    \"expiresAt\" : 1486621737213,\n    \"issuedAt\" : 1484029737213,\n    \"scopes\" : [ ],\n    \"status\" : \"approved\"\n  } ],\n  \"developerId\" : \"793e585c-f093-41d6-88e9-e235bfd087ed\",\n  \"lastModifiedAt\" : 1484049963233,\n  \"lastModifiedBy\" : \"suvojitc@rssoftware.co.in\",\n  \"name\" : \"CustomerApp\",\n  \"scopes\" : [ ],\n  \"status\" : \"approved\"\n}",
  "status": {
   "message": "OK",
   "code": "200"
  }
  };
  
  
  
  var str = JSON.stringify(json);
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  console.log(obj.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]);
  console.log(obj.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"]);
  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```